# JavaScript: Why is []==![]?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I noticed that `[]==![]` result is `true`. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKbYs/)

I don't understand this result. Can you explain why?

Comment: @zengr: I don't know. That looks like a completely different question to me.

Comment: @BoltClock: [] in boolean context is true and ![] is thus false, after that the code is doing [] == false, which results in true.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: That's not fully correct - `[1]` is true in boolean context, yet `![1]` is false and `[1] == false` also yields false. It's not the boolean context but the `==` algorithm.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree with @Antti. The answer describes in detail about the conversion of `[]` and `![]`, which answers this question.

Comment: @zengr: That doesn't make it the same question.

Comment: @pimvdb I was only pointing out that `[] == ![]` is equivalent to `[] == false` (the `![]` evaluating to `false` should be trivial), and all interesting things that happen after that should already have been covered in all prior questions & answers. There is not much point in allowing yet another question-answer thread for questions like "why `[] != !'a'` is false?".

Comment: Not to be confused with [`[] !== []`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13757109/1529630)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[]` is an array, but `![]` is a boolean value. Whenever you try to compare two objects with different types with `==` both objects should be transformed into comparable objects (using `ToNumber`, see step 7. in 11.9.3). This is why `[] == ![]` yields true, the first empty array gets evaluated to `false`.

> #### [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as 
>   follows:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, 
>      return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, 
>      return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 8. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, 
>      return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, 
>      return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 10. Return false.

However, if you use the strict type comparison operator `===` the result is false, since both types differ:

> #### [11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6)
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed 
>   as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    1. If x is NaN, return false.
>    2. If y is NaN, return false.
>    3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    4. If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
>    5. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
>    6. Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and 
>      same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

Comment: Please elaborate "transformed into comparable objects. This is why [] == ![] yields true". This answer looks like speculation without proof. RE: Edit: Still insufficient. The relevant part is section 11.9.3. You could follow the defined steps to get to the right conclusion.

Comment: @RobW: I noticed my error and removed the wrong equality operator. Took me a little while to load ECMA-262.pdf, my connection is slow as BASIC.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks bookmarked it. I also saved a copy on my HDD, this should come in handy

Comment: What is happening with `[]==![]` is an abstract equality comparison between `[]` and `![]`

Note that `typeof(![])` is `boolean` and `typeof([])` is `object`. From the documentation

For x == y, If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

ToNumber of `![]` that is `false` is 0

So, it comes down to

    [] == 0 

and the result of `[]==0` is `true`

Comment: @kidmenot: Apparently it's still way too early on a Saturday morning. Fixed my answer.

Comment: One thing to note is that the array is first converted to string by ToPrimitive, thus `[]`, `[ "" ]`, `[ null ]`, and `[ undefined ]` still become `''`, and `'' == 0` is `true`. But `[ "", "" ]` becomes `","` and `"," == 0` is `false`, because `ToNumber(',')` evaluates to `NaN`.