# lodash's .sortedUniq() doesn't seem to remove duplicates. How does it work?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given `someArr`, (an array of `php` timestamps, which will later be converted to `javascript` timestamps (`*=1000`)), I was expecting `lodash`s...

```
_.sortedUniq(someArr)
```

to remove all duplicate values, giving the same result as

```
Array.from(new Set(someArr))
```

Could anyone explain why [`.sortedUniq()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortedUniq) doesn't remove duplicates? I also tried `_.uniq()`, for that matter. Is my assumption wrong? Is there something wrong with my dataset?

Here's the [`mcve`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lydk7euc/).
The question itself refers to after I define `allVals`, but I've left the way I'm constructing it in, just in case there's something wrong with how I'm doing that. The initial dataset array is what's coming from `php` and, for the time being, is not negotiable in terms of structure.

Please note that, while I do have a bit of exercise in `javascript`, I'm not a *"schooled"* programmer, I come from a design background and learned to code hands-on, so I'm not excluding the possibility that my grasp of certain programming patterns is not `100%` accurate.

Thorough explanations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_.sortedUniq` is designed for an array that's already been sorted. Your array has not been sorted.

Replacing it with `_.uniq` seems to work in removing the duplicates. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1xvmmmc/1/))

It is possible to remove duplicates from an array more efficiently if you know it has already been sorted. That, presumably, is why LoDash includes different functions for the two cases - sorted and non-sorted.

By the way `uniqKeys === pointKeys` [will not correctly check whether the two arrays have the same contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757109/triple-equal-signs-return-false-for-arrays-in-javascript-why), as the arrays are distinct objects even if they contain the same numbers. Instead you need to write a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript) to do this, or use [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual).

Comment: I see, so I should actually do `_.sortedUniq(_.uniq(someArr))` - which indeed works. I do believe their current description: *"This method is like _.uniq except that it's designed and optimized for sorted arrays."* is kind of confusing. Upon reading it again, I tend to interpret it as I would first need to sort the array and than use `_.sortedUniq()` on it. While waiting for an answer here I found this which gives the expected output: `[...(new Set(someArr)].sort()`. No idea on performance yet, and it's going to be an issue (i'll typically get ~20k datasets from server). Thank you.

Comment: No, you would need something like `someArr.sort(); var uniques = _.sortedUniq(someArr)`, or just `_.uniq(someArr);` if you don't want to sort it first.

Comment: I see. Sort first, remove dupes after. Got it! [`fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lydk7euc/3/). Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to lodash docs (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortedUniq) _.sortedUniq is for sorted arrays, try using _.uniq()