# Basic level non-repetitive random in JS

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to make a quiz, and I need 5 random questions, to make it work I created random variables(rnd-rnd5) because I needed these variables in two functions. I need to make non-repetitive variables, but the solution below doesn't work. I need "basic" solutions if possible, because our teacher wants us to have a code that is "on our level".

```
var rnd = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0];
var rnd2 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0];
while (rnd2 !== rnd){
    rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}

var rnd3 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0];
while (rnd3 !== rnd && rnd3 !== rnd2){
    rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}

var rnd4 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0];
while (rnd4 !== rnd && rnd4 !== rnd2 && rnd4 !== rnd3){
    rnd4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}
var rnd5 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0];
while (rnd5 !== rnd && rnd5 !== rnd2 && rnd5 !== rnd3 && rnd5 !== rnd4){
    rnd5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}
```

Comment: You are generating an *array* with a single random number as a member. It seems like you don't want that, so just drop all `[` and `]` from the code and it should work.

Comment: create an array of your numbers, 0 to 29, shuffle it, then pick first 5 items, simple

Comment: Also, your logic is flipped, you need `===` instead of `!==`

Comment: "but the solution below doesn't work" if that text appears in a question and the OP doesn't explain how it isn't working, the question is not complete. It's not enough to just put code in.

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems:

1. You are generating an *array* with a single member which is a random number. Arrays are [always **not** equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757109/triple-equal-signs-return-false-for-arrays-in-javascript-why) to other arrays and any other value than themselves. It appears as if you want a plain variable, so you just need to remove the `[` and `]` surrounding the `Math.floor` calls.
2. You also have the checks backwards - you are generating new numbers if the the current one is **not equal** to the old one. Which means you are generating until the two are the same. You just need to do the opposite check `===` instead.
3. You are checking using AND `&&` where you need to check using `OR` to catch if *any* of the previous numbers was matched.

This results in the working code:

```js
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
var rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
while (rnd2 === rnd){
    rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}

var rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
while (rnd3 === rnd || rnd3 === rnd2){
    rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}

var rnd4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
while (rnd4 === rnd || rnd4 === rnd2 || rnd4 === rnd3){
    rnd4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}
var rnd5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
while (rnd5 === rnd || rnd5 === rnd2 || rnd5 === rnd3 || rnd5 === rnd4){
    rnd5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 0;
}

console.log(rnd, rnd2, rnd3, rnd4, rnd5)
```

With that said, you can generate random non-repeating numbers easier if you [generate *non*-random numbers first, then jumble them and pick however many you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100/2380105#2380105).

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of numbers

```
var numbers = [];
for(var i=0; i<30; ++i) numbers.push(i);
```

Shuffle the numbers by going from 0 to 29 (i), in each cycle pick a random number 0-29 (j) and swap the values at indexes i, j.

```
for(var i=0; i<30; ++i) {
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
  var tmp = numbers[i];
  numbers[i] = numbers[j];
  numbers[j] = tmp;
}
```

First n numbers (5) are random and unique:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; ++i) {
  console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```